# Depth feed from Kinect not updating

Tags: c++, opencv, libraries, kinect, depth

I'm using a combination of OpenKinect and OpenCV libraries to apply Haar-like feature recognition to both RGB and depth images.

I can get the live feed and successfully detect objects using the RGB feed however the depth is giving me massive problems.

After the initial frame the depth frame does not seem to update at all.

The depth callback function that provides the raw data is as follows:

```
//depth callback function
void depth_cb(freenect_device *dev, void *v_depth, uint32_t timestamp)
{
    if (got_depth == 0){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&buf_mutex);

        //copy to OpenCV buffer
        memcpy(depthMat.data, v_depth, (640*480*2));
       // depthMat.convertTo(depthFrame, CV_8UC1, 256.0/2048.0);
        got_depth++;

        pthread_cond_signal(&frame_cond);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&buf_mutex);
    }
}
```

the Mats used are initialised like so:

```
cv::Mat depthMat(cv::Size(640,480),CV_16UC1);
cv::Mat depthFrame(cv::Size(640,480),CV_8UC1);
```

And in the main function I try use them like so:

```
        depthMat.convertTo(depthFrame, CV_8UC1, 255.0/2048.0);

        imshow("rgb", rgbMat);
        imshow("depth-pre-conversion", depthMat);
        imshow("depth", depthFrame);

        IplImage depthImage = depthFrame;
        IplImage rgbImage = rgbMat;

        detect_and_draw(&depthImage);
```

'Depth-pre-conversion' is a almost black frame, you can just about make out the depth image here. It doesn't update.

'Depth' is the lighter version once converted to 8 bits, it also doesn't move.

'rgb' is the live RGB feed which works no problem (although it is BGR rather than RGB but I'll get round fixing that at some point, it's less important right now)

I'd appreciate any advise and help you can offer.